# How to change all external links color in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

How to change all external links color in wordpress, i've published my whole site now i want to convert my all external links into button so is there any way please have a look on my site : [firmwareflashfile.in](https://firmwareflashfile.in/)
Please suggest me any plugin or simple css codes

Answer (score 3):

In you case you could probably target them all with the following selector

```
a[href^="http://"]:not([href~="firmwareflashfile.in"]) {
  color: red !important;
}
```

this will target all links that start with http:// excluding the ones containing you website domain "firmwareflashfile.in" (will exclude possible anchor links that may start with #)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQ and change color of every link:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("firmwareflashfile.in") > -1) {
   alert("your url contains the name firmwareflashfile.in");
}else{
   jQuery('a').css('color','#000000');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

do you only want to change the color or do you want to convert every link into a button?

to change the color:

```
a:link { 
    color: your color;
}
```